# Custom types in graphQL schema through api platform

Tags: graphql, postgis, api-platform.com

I'm using postgres extension POSTGIS and longitudeOne package in Symfony.
So in my entity I have an attribute called coordinates which is a "point" type.
But when I'm trying to get through a graphQL query a collection of entities, the attribute is not in my schema... The issue surely comes from the custom type but I don't find a way to make it recognize in my schema...

What I would like to get is

```
query
{
  destinations
  {
    collection
    {
     id
     coordinates
    }
  }
}
```

What I have:

```
query
{
  destinations
  {
    collection
    {
     id
    }
  }
}
```

And if I force the coordinates attributes, it says :

> Cannot query field "coordinates" on type "Destination".

Comment: You need to create custom type. You can check official documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#custom-types

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL through api platform in the 2.8 version, only allows basic types, as string, int and arrays. When you create a new attribute to the entity through the symfony cli, the getters and the setters are automatically created.

For example:

> If I create a new entity called NewEntity. I will have a setNewEntity
> method and a getNewEntity method, that are based on the type the
> entity have.

The get method is important has it will be used by api platform to return the data in your graphql response. And this is where you can format the data the way you want.

In my geometry example, when I create the 'myCoordinates' attribute, I will have a getMyCoordinates attribute automatically generated. It will also automatically return an answer of type 'point'. Which can't be read by graphQL. So you can modify the get method to return a basic type, here I modify the get method to return an array type instead of a point type:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: "point")]
private $myCoordinates;

public function getMyCoordinates(): ?array
{
    if ($this->myCoordinates) {
        return [
            "longitude" => $this->myCoordinates->getLongitude(),
            "latitude" => $this->myCoordinates->getLatitude()
        ];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```